# AppFabric 1.1 Session State Caching and Distributed Caching Configuration

Tags: caching, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I have 0 experience of AppFabric but was given a task while some people were on vacation.

First question is, don't you need to configure Session State Caching and Distributed Cache on the server hosting AppFabric before you can code against it and use it?

If so where do I find information on how to do it cause I can't find any?

If not, where do I find information on what I need to include for each cache (this is for Sharepoint 2013 apps)?

Anyone who has expiernce that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session State Caching doesn't require any server-side setup, it's purely [client side](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361711%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), using the `AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider` class. For Sharepoint and AppFabric, there's a [overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2013/03/27/appfabric-caching-and-sharepoint-1.aspx) and [configuration guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2013/03/27/appfabric-caching-and-sharepoint-2.aspx) on MSDN, and [a page on how to manage the Sharepoint Distributed Cache service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx) on technet with [an associated download on configuration and installation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35557)

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's the same with Distributed cache I guess?